# Superstitious - How to use with a person's name?

Tags: word-usage, meaning

Below mentioned is an excerpts from **Crime and Punishment** by **Fyodor Dostoyevsky**.

What is the meaning of the bolded phrase below? I know what *superstitious* means, but I don't understand how it can be used with a person.

> She had a large connection, because she was very honest and always stuck to her price: there was no higgling to be done with her. She was a woman of few words and very shy and reserved. But **Raskolnikoff was very superstitious**, and traces of this remained in him long after.

Comment: Note that the sentence in which your bolded phrase occurs begins a new paragraph - it is not continuous with what you quote previously, and indeed it takes several paragraphs for Dostoevsky to clarify the connection.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Saying that *somebody is superstitious* means that person is inclined to believe in superstition.

It is used like most of the adjectives that modify a person. Somebody can be *superstitious* in the same way that they can be *kind* or *smart*.